# svg gradient fill animation percentage jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, linear-gradients

I'm trying to get some svg animation with jquery, for each class "check" i need summs percentage offset for gradient, and when this class is remove need reduce percentage offset gradient. This all need animation down up when class added, and up down when class removed.

So i got, gradient and get offset to 5% percentage. Trying to get array but stuck. Think about get all elements with class "check" and try to summs for each class.

```js
 var firstStop = document.getElementById('F1gst1');
 percentage = '5%'; firstStop.setAttribute('offset',percentage);

$(".analysis-li").click(function(){

       $(this).toggleClass("check");
          if($(this).hasClass('check')){
        
          }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <li class="analysis-li"></li>
    <li class="analysis-li"></li>
    <li class="analysis-li"></li>
    <li class="list analysis-li"></li>
    <li class="analysis-li"></li>
    <li class="list analysis-li"></li>
    <li class="analysis-li" ></li>
 
    <svg class="thermometr" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44.3 333.8">
                <linearGradient y2="0%" x2="0%" y1="100%" x1="0%" id="F1g"><stop stop-color="#00FF00" offset="0%" id="F1gst1"/><stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0%" id="F1gst2"/></linearGradient>
                <path fill="url(#F1g)" class="st0" d="M30.5 297.5V4.6c0-2.5-2.1-4.6-4.6-4.6-2.5 0-4.6 2.1-4.6 4.6v292.9c-7.9 2-13.8 9.2-13.8 17.8 0 10.2 8.2 18.4 18.4 18.4s18.4-8.2 18.4-18.4c0-8.5-5.9-15.7-13.8-17.8"/><path fill="url(#F1g)" class="st0"  d="M9 290.2h7.5v.5H9zM9 284.3h7.5v.6H9zM9 278.4h7.5v.5H9zM9 272.5h7.5v.6H9zM0 266.6h16.5v.6H0zM9 260.7h7.5v.5H9zM9 254.8h7.5v.6H9zM9 248.9h7.5v.5H9zM9 243h7.5v.6H9zM0 237.1h16.5v.6H0zM9 231.3h7.5v.5H9zM9 225.4h7.5v.6H9zM9 219.5h7.5v.6H9zM9 213.6h7.5v.6H9zM0 207.7h16.5v.6H0zM9 201.8h7.5v.6H9zM9 195.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 190h7.5v.6H9zM9 184.1h7.5v.5H9zM0 178.2h16.5v.6H0zM9 172.3h7.5v.6H9zM9 166.4h7.5v.5H9zM9 160.5h7.5v.6H9zM9 154.7h7.5v.6H9zM0 148.8h16.5v.6H0zM9 142.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 137h7.5v.5H9zM9 131.1h7.5v.5H9zM9 125.2h7.5v.6H9zM0 119.3h16.5v.5H0zM9 113.4h7.5v.6H9zM9 107.5h7.5v.6H9zM9 101.6h7.5v.5H9zM9 95.7h7.5v.6H9zM0 89.8h16.5v.6H0zM9 83.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 78.1h7.5v.6H9zM9 72.2h7.5v.6H9zM9 66.3h7.5v.6H9zM0 60.4h16.5v.6H0zM9 54.8h7.5v.6H9zM9 48.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 43h7.5v.5H9zM9 37.1h7.5v.6H9zM0 31.2h16.5v.5H0zM9 26h7.5v.6H9zM9 20.1h7.5v.5H9zM9 14.2h7.5v.6H9zM9 8.3h7.5v.6H9zM0 2.4h16.5V3H0z"/>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. In order to animate the gradient I'm using `requestAnimationFrame`. I'm animating the second stop offset between 10% and 100% but you can choose the values you want.

Please read the comments in the code.

```js
 // the second stop
 let laststop = document.getElementById('F1gst2');
 // a variable used to toggle the animation
 let n = 0;
 // the target value of the offset attribute
 let target;
 // the actual value of the offset attribute
 let val = 10;
 //the request animation frame id
 let rid = null;

$(".analysis-li").click(function(){
   
   n++;
   // set the target value
   if(n%2 == 1){
     target = 100; 
   }else{target = 10}
    // if there is an animation stop it  
    if(rid){cancelAnimationFrame(rid); rid="null"}
    // call the frame function
    frame()      
});


function frame(){
  rid = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  //the distance between the value and the target value
  dist = target - val;
  //increase the value
  val += dist/10;
  // set the offset value
  laststop.setAttributeNS(null,"offset",`${val}%`)
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:30px}
path{stroke:black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="analysis-li">click here</p>
<svg class="thermometr" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44.3 333.8" >
                <linearGradient y2="0%" x2="0%" y1="100%" x1="0%" id="F1g">
                  <stop stop-color="#00FF00" offset="0%" id="F1gst1"/>
                  <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="10%" id="F1gst2"/>
                </linearGradient>
                <path fill="url(#F1g)" class="st0" d="M30.5 297.5V4.6c0-2.5-2.1-4.6-4.6-4.6-2.5 0-4.6 2.1-4.6 4.6v292.9c-7.9 2-13.8 9.2-13.8 17.8 0 10.2 8.2 18.4 18.4 18.4s18.4-8.2 18.4-18.4c0-8.5-5.9-15.7-13.8-17.8"/>
  <path fill="url(#F1g)" class="st0"  d="M9 290.2h7.5v.5H9zM9 284.3h7.5v.6H9zM9 278.4h7.5v.5H9zM9 272.5h7.5v.6H9zM0 266.6h16.5v.6H0zM9 260.7h7.5v.5H9zM9 254.8h7.5v.6H9zM9 248.9h7.5v.5H9zM9 243h7.5v.6H9zM0 237.1h16.5v.6H0zM9 231.3h7.5v.5H9zM9 225.4h7.5v.6H9zM9 219.5h7.5v.6H9zM9 213.6h7.5v.6H9zM0 207.7h16.5v.6H0zM9 201.8h7.5v.6H9zM9 195.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 190h7.5v.6H9zM9 184.1h7.5v.5H9zM0 178.2h16.5v.6H0zM9 172.3h7.5v.6H9zM9 166.4h7.5v.5H9zM9 160.5h7.5v.6H9zM9 154.7h7.5v.6H9zM0 148.8h16.5v.6H0zM9 142.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 137h7.5v.5H9zM9 131.1h7.5v.5H9zM9 125.2h7.5v.6H9zM0 119.3h16.5v.5H0zM9 113.4h7.5v.6H9zM9 107.5h7.5v.6H9zM9 101.6h7.5v.5H9zM9 95.7h7.5v.6H9zM0 89.8h16.5v.6H0zM9 83.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 78.1h7.5v.6H9zM9 72.2h7.5v.6H9zM9 66.3h7.5v.6H9zM0 60.4h16.5v.6H0zM9 54.8h7.5v.6H9zM9 48.9h7.5v.6H9zM9 43h7.5v.5H9zM9 37.1h7.5v.6H9zM0 31.2h16.5v.5H0zM9 26h7.5v.6H9zM9 20.1h7.5v.5H9zM9 14.2h7.5v.6H9zM9 8.3h7.5v.6H9zM0 2.4h16.5V3H0z"/>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG created programmicaly, only one shape is translated by incoming value:

```js
let path = (y, d, extra) => `<path d="${d}" transform="translate(0,${y})" ${extra||''}></path>`
let multi = (count, html) => Array(count).fill(0).map((e, i) => html(i)).join('');
let toggle = el => el.classList.toggle('on') | 
   rect.setAttribute('y', 14.6*(7-document.querySelectorAll("path.on").length)+8)
scale.innerHTML = multi(10, i => path(i*10, 'M60,10h10M65,12h5M65,14h5M65,16h5M65,18h5'));
checks.innerHTML = multi(7, i => path(i*12, 'M10,10v8h8v-8z', 'class="on" onclick="toggle(this)"') +
                                 path(i*12, 'M12,14l2.2,2l2.2,-4'))
```

```css
g#scale path { 
  stroke: white; 
  stroke-width: 0.7; 
}

#checks { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 20px; 
  left: 20px; 
}

#checks path {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke: #f5b53a;
  cursor:pointer;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
}

#checks path.on + path {
  opacity:1;
}

#checks path:nth-child(2n) {
 opacity: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
 transition: 0.5s;
 stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 135 135" height="90vh" style="background-color:purple">
  <defs><mask id="termometer">
    <path d="M80,10v100" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <circle r="10" cy="120" cx="80" fill="white"></circle>
    <g id="scale"></g>
  </mask></defs>
  <rect width="130" height="130" mask="url(#termometer)" fill="white"></rect>
  <rect id="rect" style="transition:1s" y="8" width="130" height="130" 
        mask="url(#termometer)" fill="#f5b53a"></rect>
  <g id="checks"></g>
</svg>
```